# Why does the button move to the current window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use the `tkinter` function to create a new window, it works fine.
When I link from this window to another window, the button moves to the first window. I don't understand why it moves.

Here is the code for the first window,

```
    import tkinter
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title ("Login")
    window.geometry ("300x150") 
    username = "Gurdip"
    password = "1234"
    def login():
         if txtUser.get() == username and txtPass.get() == password:
         import NewWindow
    lblUser = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username:")
    lblUser.pack()
    txtUser = tkinter.Entry(window)
    txtUser.pack()
    lblPass = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password:")
    lblPass.pack()
    txtPass = tkinter.Entry(window)
    txtPass.pack()
    btnenter = tkinter.Button(window, text="Enter", command=login)
    btnenter.pack()
```

And for the second window

```
    import tkinter
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title ("The Royal Liberty School")
    window.geometry ("300x150")
    def webpage():
         import webbrowser
         webbrowser.open("http://www.royalliberty.org.uk/")
    lblRlib = tkinter.Label(window, text="Welcome to the Royal Liberty School\n\nClick the link to go to our website")
    lblRlib.pack()
    def button():
         webbutton = tkinter.Button(text ="Royal Liberty School", command = webpage)
         webbutton.pack()
    button()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Buttons don't generally "move". Are you saying the button actually moves across the screen from one window to another? Also, are these two separate tkinter programs, or is all this code combined into one program?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're reporting that the "Royal Liberty School" button is *appearing* on the wrong window, rather than actually *moving*. I've never heard of a button moving before.

if that guess is correct, it's probably because you aren't giving it an explicit parent, so it's defaulting to the root window.

If all of that code belongs to a single program, you have another problem. You should always only ever create a single instance of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both by the name *window*. This means that there are two windows on the screen both acsessed by the name window. It is more conventional to use tkinter's Toplevel as follows

```
NewWindow = Toplevel(window)
```

Then, any items you want to place on this NewWindow,  just use it in the place of window

```
MyButton = Button(NewWindow, text=hi)
```

As the other answer said, it is incorrect to have to *Tk()* in one program so you must use the Toplevel.